# JavaScript about .push()

Tags: javascript

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

```js
var collection = {
        1245: {
          artist: "Robert Palmer",
          tracks: [ ]
        },
        5439: {
          album: "ABBA Gold"
        }
    };

    var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

    function update(id, prop, value) {
      if (value !== '' && prop == 'tracks') {
        collectionCopy[id][prop].push(value);

      return collectionCopy;
    }

    update(1245, "tracks", "Addicted to Love");
```

---

It says collectionCopy[id][prop].push(value) is not a function, i don't know why,but collectionCopy[id][prop] is actually an array.
Thanks for help!

Comment: The code you posted is syntactically incorrect and therefore cannot produce the error you say you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a } in your if statement in update().  Fixed up code below works just fine:

```
var collection = {
        1245: {
          artist: "Robert Palmer",
          tracks: [ ]
        },
        5439: {
          album: "ABBA Gold"
        }
    };

    var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

    function update(id, prop, value) {
      if (value !== '' && prop == 'tracks') {
        collectionCopy[id][prop].push(value);
      }
      return collectionCopy;
    }

    update(1245, "tracks", "Addicted to Love");
```

Output:

```
{ 1245: { artist: 'Robert Palmer', tracks: [ 'Addicted to Love' ] },
  5439: { album: 'ABBA Gold' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is not correctly closed. Try to structure your code more neatly using an IDE which can usually do this for you. The code should be the following:

```js
var collection = {
  1245: {
    artist: "Robert Palmer",
    tracks: []
  },
  5439: {
    album: "ABBA Gold"
  }
};

var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

function update(id, prop, value) {
  if (value !== '' && prop == 'tracks') {
    collectionCopy[id][prop].push(value);
    return collectionCopy;
  }
}

update(1245, "tracks", "Addicted to Love");

console.log(collection);
```